# Show the summary in the title card

Tags: php, wordpress

I want the summary to appear instead of the title when the card is hovered over.
That is, instead of:

```
<div class="cardpro-main" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">
```

I want to use the following code:

```
<div class="cardpro-main" title="<?php the_excerpt(); ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">
```

When I use the code: `title="<?php the_excerpt(); ?>"`; The summary is displayed as: `<p>summary</p>`.

Is there a way to hide the `<p></p>` tag?

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php . You'll need to use [get_the_excerpt](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/) in order to use this

Comment: Developer Please check my answer i have updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this it will not show the p tag

```
    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
```

As per your requirement below is the full code.

```
<div class="cardpro-main" title="<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">
```

Comment: [`the_excerpt()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/) simply does an `echo get_the_excerpt()`. That means the output cannot be different unless there is a filter applied on `the_excerpt` that is not also applied on `get_the_excerpt`

Comment: Hey his question is replacing the p tag if you apply filter then it will remove p tag from all the places where the excerpt is applied. So to avoid that i replaced the_except with get_the_excerpt according to his requirement. Please see the suggestion and requirement and do down vote on others answers

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. What should I do if I just want to remove [...] from the end of the summary?

Comment: yes, but you should explain why that happens because just looking at the docs for the functions is not clear to whoever actually wants to learn something. In this case, there is a default WP filter applied on `the_excerpt` that uses the `wpautop()` callback which adds the `<p>` tags. Your answer is not wrong, it's just incomplete :)

Comment: Developer you can apply the filter in the functions.php of the child theme. filter can be taken from here https://www.shabujamespaul.com/remove-excerpt/